# Google Charts: How to pass a JSON data to ChartWrapper()?

Tags: php, json, ajax, charts

Though I successfully created and displayed my chart using drawChart() function, but, when I tried to load the chart editor by passing the same JSON in dataSourceUrl in ChartWrapper() function, the editor loaded but chart did not. What should I change in the code to retrieve the charts by passing JSON data when using Chart Editor? Here's the code:

```
    <?php
      $result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM googlechart');

      /*
          ---------------------------
          example data: Table (googlechart)
          --------------------------
          weekly_task     percentage
          Sleep           30
          Watching Movie  10
          job             40
          Exercise        20       
      */



      $rows = array();
      $table = array();
      $table['cols'] = array(

        array('label' => 'Weekly Task', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => 'Percentage', 'type' => 'number')

    );

        foreach($result as $r) {

          $temp = array();

          // the following line will be used to slice the Pie chart

          $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['weekly_task']); 

          // Values of each slice

          $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['percentage']); 
          $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
        }

    $table['rows'] = $rows;

    // convert data into JSON format
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
    echo $jsonTable;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    ?>


    <html>
      <head>
        <!--Load the Ajax API-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {packages: ['charteditor']});
  </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        google.setOnLoadCallback(loadEditor);
    var chartEditor = null;
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable+'(<?php=$jsonTable; ?>)';

    function loadEditor() {
      // Create the chart to edit.
      var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
         'chartType':'LineChart',
         'dataSourceUrl':'data', //**This is the area where I've my doubt.    //It's not accepting JSON data and showing 404 error.**

         'options': {'title':'My Daily Routine', 'legend':'none'}
      });

      chartEditor = new google.visualization.ChartEditor();
      google.visualization.events.addListener(chartEditor, 'ok', redrawChart);
      chartEditor.openDialog(wrapper, {});
    }

    // On "OK" save the chart to a <div> on the page.
    function redrawChart(){
      chartEditor.getChartWrapper().draw(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    }

        </script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <!--this is the div that will hold the pie chart-->
        <div id="chart_div"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you really setting `dataSourceUrl` to the character literal `"data"`? If so, it's not surprising that you're getting a 404. `"data"` isn't a url!

Comment: That's the thing I actually want to learn. Instead of passing data from a url I want to pass a JSON data. What changes should I make to achieve so? To be more precise, what parameter should I use instead of dataSourceUrl?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?hl=en#chartwrapper-class

Comment: @Simon M Kenzie  Thank you Sir...its working. I can't believe I didn't see the answer was in same page!